# Trying to get Formula for Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to create a formula that converts a column of strings (If a string is available) into a larger string. See the google spreadsheet example in the attached.
Is this possible? Please help me make a formula.

Column A to E is the input, Column H should contain the formula that displays the expected result.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bOMkEgzhyoZHNv2Z9dCQ7qcDGb36CTN9fnMo9wJ7cqU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! Could you provide (in the body of your question, ideally) an example of what the expected output should be for a set of inputs? Could you share what formulas you have tried already, and why they didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a new tab on your sheet with this formula in h1.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Output";IF(A2:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(A2:A," ","_")&" = "&IF(B2:B="","['"&A2:A&"']","['"&TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:G&CHAR(10)),,7)),CHAR(10)&" ","', '"))&"']"))})
```

Does that work?